# Build a software raid 1 on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, raid

I have nothing but bad experiences in using built in raid controller.

Is there a possibility to use the software raid features of windows 2003 in Windows XP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows XP Pro is capable of software RAID levels 0, 1 or 5. In order to get levels 1 and 5 some modified files have to be installed. I've been using Windows XP Pro with RAID 5 as file server for movies for 6 months now and have had no problems at all. If you're interested here's a pretty easy to follow tutorial [Software RAID 0, 1, 5 or JBOD Using Windows XP Pro SP3](http://www.optimiz3.com/low-cost-and-reliable-network-attatched-software-jbod-raid-0-1-or-5/). If you run into any problems just ask a question in the comments and the admin will  answer them quickly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP Pro allow you to define software RAID volumes, but only RAID 0, see this tutorial:
www.techimo.com/articles/index.pl?photo=149

If you want to configure RAID 1 or RAID 5 volumes on Windows XP this will require some hacking. If you google for "windows XP software RAID" there are plenty of tutorials on how to enable this features on Windows XP

Answer (score 2):

> I have nothing but bad experiences in
>   using built in raid controller.

I can only assume that you're using consumer level nVidia or generic BIOS level RAID on a workstation. Avoid on-board RAID solutions as they're all junk. There are varying differences in RAID solutions. Your *best* best for doing *real* RAID is to get an actual card.

I highly discourage doing software RAID especially on Windows as performance won't be too bad in comparison to hardware RAID, but for if you really want any level of protection from failure don't think software can supplant hardware RAID. Yes they cost money. Yes, they can be a complicated. But if you want RAID to work *for* you, you have to invest in the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the software raid features by right clicking on your "My Computer" icon, choosing "Manage", and then click the "Disk Management" entry in the tree on the left side of the window that opens.  Look for any disks listed as "dynamic" (odds are your system volume is currently "basic") and right click on them to get a menu of tasks you can perform.

Answer (score -1):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307880/EN-US/

EDIT: nevermind, misread the title